# Ubuntu 14.04 won't let me login

Tags: update-manager, startup, login-screen, macbook-pro

Yesterday I was updating some applications. I come back later and I see a red stop sign on top of my screen that stated there was an error. It said that some of my packages needed some dependencies. I ignored it and shut off my laptop. Now Ubuntu starts up and takes me to my login screen but freezes. I can't move the mouse or type in my password. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

I hope this was clear enough, I'm a newbie with ubuntu. I have a 2012 macbook pro 15inch.

Comment: Its necessary to know what packages you were updating and the error that was showing on the screen afterwards. Can you recall these? Is no key working?

Comment: Get into tty console (  Ctrl+Alt+F1 or any other F key ) login there,  and read through logs in /var/log directory,  namely you'd be interested in dmesg and syslog.  Look for errors and warnings.  Probably good idea is to mount a usb and copy those to usb, and post them here or ar least portions of them

Comment: I cant get into tty1 console using ctr+alt+f1. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Get into tty1 console (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and login there.

Type the commands

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get -f install`

This should install any missing dependencies

Comment: I cant get into tty1 console using ctr+alt+f1. Any other suggestion?

Comment: check with f1-f9, you'll get in at some combo.